# Detect select option change without javascript

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have this dropdown list:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>
```

and some text like this:

```
<h2>xxx</h2>
```

I want to replace "xxx" with the value of the selected option from the dropdown. I know how to do this in javascript, query...

My question is more if there is some hack to make this work in **html/css only**.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Why don't you want to use Javascript for this?

Comment: @Mark the html is intended to be sent by email (a html email). It will be blocked by email clients

Comment: @Monta That's a though one, not all email clients follow the standard. It's hard to do advanced effects on them.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I agree

Comment: @Monta I think it's best to keep e-mail simple as possible. Even don't use input/select elements. I style all my e-mails with tables for the layout even (yeah it's disgusting) because div elements are often rendered weirdly in some clients.  Al tough a bit outdated, this might be a nice start to check universally supported elements and styles: https://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if option is check with CSS property `:checked` (do that : `option:checked`), but you can't change text with only HTML or CSS.
I try to display `h2` element with `:checked` and brother property like that :

```
<select>
    <option value="1">
        <p>Audi</p>
        <h2>Audi</h2>
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        <p>BMW</p>
        <h2>BMW</h2>
    </option>
</select>
```

But it's impossible to put something other than text

Comment: Thank you but my text I want to change is somewhere else in the DOM outside the select